# Scan QR code using webcam in ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, camera

I have Final year project that implement a website. I facing a problem with implementing Scan Qr Code function.

1. I need to create a QR code scanner in my "Scan.aspx", this page will display a camera using webcam. If is phone, it will use the phone camera to scan a QR code image.
2. I no idea how to code it. My project is ASP.net web application.

Please provide me any references source code, or solution, I will code it myself. Thank in advanced.

The final result i need is similar with this, it can scan qr code automatically.

https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/scan

Comment: How i want to code it? any souce or demo?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Read/Scan Data from image/PDF or file

```
 Bitmap bmp = page.ConvertToImage(192);

        // get all barcodes
        Barcode[] barcodes = BarcodeReader.ReadBarcodes(settings, bmp);

        foreach (Barcode barcode in barcodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data: " + barcode.DataString);
        }
```

Read QR Code from Scanned Image

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(dir + "code.png");
        //  config reader setting
        ReaderSettings settings = new ReaderSettings();
        //  Type of barcode 
        settings.AddTypesToRead(BarcodeType.QRCode);

        //  read all barcodes 
        Barcode[] barcodes = BarcodeReader.ReadBarcodes(settings, bmp);

        foreach (Barcode barcode in barcodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data: " + barcode.DataString);
        }
```

Comment: The read/scan data, it will capture the qr code automatically right?

Comment: no it won't! you have to look for image capture around.